# Extracting and overwriting .zip files (.NET Framework 4.7.2.)

Tags: vb.net, unzip, overwrite

I have a program that needs to extract **.zip files**. (The program is written in **.NET Framework** 4.7.2.) In each .zip there are different folders and files. When the program **extracts** the .zip it needs to **overwrite** the old folders and files.

I am using: `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ExtractSource, ExtractDestination)`
The only problem is that I can't overwrite files with this. After searching for a long time, nothing has worked yet.

I would like to use: `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ExtractSource, ExtractDestination, true)`.
Where the "True" boolean in the code causes the files to be overwritten, but this code cannot be used in .NET Framework. Is there any code similar to this that I can use instead of mine?

I found most of the code [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_).

Can anyone help me find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use a method that is only available in .NET Core then it should be obvious that you need to either switch to .NET Core or use a different method. Your wants change nothing.

Comment: You can extract your ZIP archive to the System Temp folder, then move the extracted files to the destination folder, overwriting what's already in there.

Comment: Delete or move the original files first, then extract the files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract and overwrite the files (in **.NET Framework**) using the library: *ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib*

Installation: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/1.3.2

Useful code: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code will not need .Net core (I tested this on .Net framework 4.8)            


            string zipPath = "zip_path_of_choice";
            string extractPath = "destination_dir_of_choice";
            try
            {
                ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if(entry.FullName.EndsWith("/") || entry.FullName.EndsWith("\\"))
                    {
                        string entryFullName = entry.FullName.Replace('/', '\\');
                        string entryFullpath = Path.Combine(extractPath, entryFullName);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(entryFullpath))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(entryFullpath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string entryFullName = entry.FullName.Replace('/', '\\');
                        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entryFullName), true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```